# PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties is not able to load the property file from src/main/resources

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I am using `PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(abc.properties)`;

and have placed `abc.properties` in `src/main/resources` folder but still it's not able to get this property file.

Code that we tried ::

```
try {
 props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("abc.properties"); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
logger.error("Unable to load file", e); 
}
```

Can someone help me out with the possible cause of not picking up abc.properties whereas if I change it to application.properties, its able to load.

Comment: would u please share some code that you have tried so far ?? if any error don't forgot to share error stacktrace as well.. @Meenal

Comment: @VikrantKashyap:  try {
      props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("abc.properties");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("Unable to load file", e);
    }

Comment: Here props variable is coming as empty